# Fetch JSON & Load DOM JQM

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile, mobile

My problem is that I use jQuery Mobile in my application. And I use the jqm's built in ajax anchor page transition. Like this:

```
<a href="cards.html">Go</a>
```

Now both of the html files have the same structure.

```
<html>...<body><div data-role="page" id="home">...</div>
```

I assume the content of cards.html gets loaded into #home. But I want to proceed a getJSON server request and modify the new page before it gets loaded. So basically I want the spin bar to spin until the JSON is fetched and put into the new DOM elements.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- Set the elements of your new page hidden by default (use a class in the top HTML `<div>`)
- Show the spinner on `pageshow` event: `$(document).on("pageshow", "#cards", function(event) { $.mobile.loading("show"); }`
- In the same event handler start your JSON request
- In the "completed" callback update the DOM, hide the spinner and show all updated elements